# Bootstrap margin class for extra small screens

Tags: bootstrap-4, margin

I use such Bootstrap classes for margin like: `my-sm-3, m-0, mr-2` etc.
But I didn't find margin class only for mobile screens. `my-xs-3` doesn't work.
Do they have a class for such a case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no `xs` in Bootstrap 4. So, what you are looking for is just `my-3`.

This is because Bootstrap 4 is "mobile first".

And the same thinking is applied to other classes like column classes as well.

So, instead of `col-xs-*`, in Bootstrap 4 there is just `col-*`.

"Mobile first" means the **default** value is defined for the smallest possible screen (mobile) and then values can be modified for screens that get progressively larger. This is also known as "progressive enhancement".

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's working(margin only for 767px and smaller):  `my-3 my-md-0`. Thanks.

Comment: This is because of the "mobile first" paradigm that was adopted for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Yes, it's new for me) Sure :)

Comment: But that's like scratching your left ear with your right hand... not nice.